# Passportjs does not relay data from databse/model

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I started the journey to implement passportjs in my PERN app. I have not been able to get it to work despite numerous attempts. Even after looking at various examples. When I do console.

```
  module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=$1",[username],
        (error, user) => {
          // User.findOne({ where: { username: username } }, (error, user) => {
          if (error) return done(error, false);
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
          } else {
            console.debug(user);
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, result) => {
              if (error) return done(error, false, { msg: error.message });
              if (result === true) {
              return done(null, user);
              } else {
                return done(null, false);
              }
            });
          }
          // return done(null, user);
        }
      );
    })
  );
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.debug("serializing ", user);
  done(null, user);
});
};
```

When I do db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=$1",[username]...) and console.debug, I get something that looks like this, but not the data. Where am I not getting it right??

```
  Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_superuser',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_staff',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_librarian',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 4,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
```